# Need help understanding logcat message ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

```
    final EditText edt =findViewById(R.id.type_text);
    final TextView txt= findViewById(R.id.empty_text);
    Button   btn =      findViewById(R.id.button_add);
    final String value = edt.getText().toString();

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            txt.append(value+"\n");
            edt.setText("");
        }
    });
```

This is line 40 -->  final EditText edt =findViewById(R.id.type_text);

Logcat message 
    `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
        at com.example.todo.activitity2.onCreate(activitity2.java:40)`

Comment: Please post your xml file code. So we can help.

Comment: your "type_text" is TextInputLayout in your layout and you are trying to cast it in edit text like "final EditText edt =findViewById(R.id.type_text);" thats why it give you classCast error. try to use "final TextInputLayout tv =findViewById(R.id.type_text);"

Comment: Try to cast (TextInputEditText)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your layout XML file there is **TextInputLayout** with ID `type_text` which you are trying to convert into **EditText**.

In your XML file change this **TextInputLayout** to **EditText**

OR

In your Class.java file correct this :
`final EditText edt = findViewById(R.id.type_text);`

to

`final TextInputLayout your_name = findViewById(R.id.type_text);`

Answer (score 1):

you need to change this :

```
final EditText edt = findViewById(R.id.type_text);
```

Into the proper class : (R.id.type_text is `TextInputLayout` and you created it as `EditText` and this is what causes the exeption  )

```
final TextInputLayout edt = findViewById(R.id.type_text);
```